How can judicial independence be jeopardised by politicians' criticism?
A New Zealand minister recently called a High Court judge a "Communist Judge".
Today the Bar Association published their concerns about it. They say:

The judiciary in New Zealand can be an easy target. Judges cannot speak in defence of themselves or their judgments. The careful separation and balance of powers between our courts, government and politicians means Ministers must not engage in any personal criticism of judges or the leadership of the Courts. Just as the courts and judges, remain outside of politics.
...
It is fundamental for our democracy that judges are not the subject of personal attack or criticism by Ministers that may risk Judges being restricted in their role. Judges must be capable of being able to freely play their independent constitutional role in Aotearoa New Zealand.

This question is about how technically someone's criticism (even from a minister) can possibly adversely affect a judge's independence.
Judges are not supposed to care what anyone thinks of their decisions. Indeed, being able to bring an impartial, uninfluenced mind is essential part of their job. To be independent, they are paid top notch salaries, are provided with posh perks and are legally immune from civil claims arising out of their decisions.
Needless to say, they are not legally bound to anyhow react to whatever remarks politicians make about them. Their decisions do not lose legal power just because some politicians disagree. The only way politicians can legally affect judges' decisions is to enact new legislation.
So, just why politicians' criticism is not water off a duck's back to judges? How can they lose their independence just because some politician says something unfavorable about them? Why wouldn't they just ignore and keep doing their job?
Is that because some judges can not, despite all the legal protections, make the mental effort needed to completely ignore what powerful figures say about them? But, does this not essentially mean that these judges are not fit for the job precisely because of their inability to ignore?

In New Zealand and broadly similar countries (in terms of socioeconomic systems) the judiciary is in principle independent of politics and interprets the law without fear or favour (judicial independence). This is fundamental to the rule of law, which along with (again broadly speaking) democracy underpins these societies.
A politician accusing a judge of being a "communist judge" would lead some people to believe the judge's decision was biased by his communist beliefs. One politician doing this once may not be significant but the more people who do it, and the more it happens, the more likely it will become a social norm. Over time, this personal criticism will tend to erode the legitimacy of the institution of the judiciary in the eyes of the public. Unless the judiciary begins to deliver important judgements according to the prevailing wind.
We have seen similar behaviour in the UK, eg. the Daily Mail's front page in November 2016 with the headline "Enemies of the people", accompanied by photos of three senior High Court judges (and their house prices) and a scathing article because the judges handed down a judgment contrary to what the Daily Mail, its owners and its readership preferred, and similar personal hostility seeping into declarations made by Government ministers and other polticians.
Instead of criticising the judgment on its own merits or promoting a constructive way forward, numerous critics accused the out-of-touch, unelected (a pejorative) judges, members of a social elite who live in expensive houses, of colluding with Remainers and unscrupulous lawyers to thwart the will of the people in a shocking display of judicial activism.
This has happened time and again in relation to other sets of circumstances - personal and hostile attacks on the judge instead of substantive legal criticism of the judgment and proposals of changes to the law.
It is impossible to measure the consequences. Nevertheless, newspaper articles and letters and social media comments show there are people who seem to believe that a judgment that one disagrees with is proof of the judge's bias.
Often we don't know what we've got until it's gone. None of us are old enough to remember the time when English Kings and Queens dismissed senior judges for disagreeable judgments. But there are countries today where judicial independence is said to be at risk (e.g. Poland and Hungary) and there are other countries where there hasn't been judicial independence. These don't tend to be places where people are eager to live, rather than to leave, if you are on the 'wrong' side.

TBH making judges "political puppets" by law is bad enough, but at least everyone can see it happening. OTOH, there's the "intermediate case" when the intimidation is done by secret services etc., in private, see e.g. recent allegations/complaints in Pakistan https://www.voanews.com/a/senior-pakistan-judges-allege-intimidation-torture-by-military-run-spy-agency-/7545543.html

Isn't such behavior a "contempt of court" and thus a crime?


Judges are not supposed to care what anyone thinks of their decisions.

Indeed, and one of the things which makes this possible is that there aren't intimidation campaigns against judges for their decisions. If a judge has to worry that their rulings will be ammunition for a politician to stir up a frenzied mob who thinks they are a dangerous communist (or some other pejorative), then their reasonable fear for their personal safety could weigh on their mind, causing them to adjudicate cases in a way which is not solely directed by the facts and the law.
Note that "fear for their personal safety" could span a whole range of things, from protestors showing up outside the judge's home, to death threats, to physical violence. And these things don't actually have to have happened for a judge to reasonably fear that further verbal attacks by high-profile politicians could incite them in the future.

This makes sense at first glance. However, I think that potential threats are "normal" part of judges' daily routine. One side in their cases will always be unhappy, and many of them will be prepared to do stuff from "showing up outside the judge's home, to death threats". I don't buy that a politician saying something makes a whole lot of difference.

@Greendrake Judges are absolutely not subject to threats and personal insults normally. The rules in court ensure judges are treated with respect at all times, with anyone who breaks those rules punished severely. Attempting to threaten or influence a judge is a serious offence, punishable by long sentences.

@StuartF Nothing in this question relates to what happens in court. In NZ, people are free to criticize (and even insult) judges outside court however they like except for intentionally publishing false statements. Threats get treated like with ordinary people i.e. investigated by the police.

@Greendrake People being unhappy with judges' rulings in their own cases are one thing, demagogues using their public platforms to fan flames is another thing. Take Judge Tanya Chutkin in the US as an example: she has received death threats from Donald Trump's supporters. Obviously one side in Trump's actual case will be unhappy, but nobody seriously expects either Trump or special prosecutor Jack Smith to make such threats themselves if the trial doesn't go their way.

@kaya3 Another good example is Mike Pence. The guy did the bare minimum of his job at the latest possible moment, and "a politician" still managed to rile up a mob bringing hanging equipment. Really, Donald Trump's entire political career is built on the notion that what politicians say, and especially what words they use, does in fact make an enormous difference.

@xLeitix Mike Pence is not a judge.

@Greendrake: Your average person does not have influence over huge segments of a country (or subdivision thereof)'s population.  Politicians generally do.

Judges are people, not automatons
To say they don’t care what anybody thinks about them or their decisions is absurd.
Criticism is damaging. Unjust criticism that you can’t respond to is even more damaging.
Bringing a fair and impartial mind is essential to the job, and worrying about what ministers, the media, and the public are going to say about it adversely affects their ability to do that.

Disclaimer: I don't know anything about the specific situation in New Zealand.
But just in general, it sound like the minister is accusing the judge of not being impartial. I mean he does so in no uncertain terms implying a political bias.
I'd suppose he would have carefully regulated means to actually probe the legality of the judges decision as well as the legislative means to change the law so that the judge would be bound to come to a different decision.
But rather than going though this long, hard and tedious process, the minister apparently tries to circumvent the official path and tries to go for populism and judging the judge in "the court of public opinion".
Needless to say the court of public opinion is full of layman judges who speak more from their gut feelings than from legal expertise and given a questionable legal education, it's often enough much easier to sway public opinion with fallacies and legal inaccuracies that borderline abuse liberties granted by free speech in order to make arguments that would not hold any water in an actual court and that might be bordering lies, libel and slander.
But judges, taking politicians to court over personal matters are probably likewise carefully regulated and even if not, are really not great PR for either side and able to set dangerous precedent (judges abusing power over the legislative branch). So yeah not sure you could go there or would want to go there.
Now again the general public has several legal options to rectify a problem if they see fit, including elections, appealing to courts, sometimes they can make legal proposals directly or indirectly, but the court of public opinion is mostly about shit talking gossip and publicly tearing a persons reputation and private life to shreds. So at the end of the day judges are still human being with families friends and a life outside of the job. And if the thought leaders representing significant portions of the population (if they are ministers they are government and if they are government I presume they represent at least double digit percentages...) that can result in significant public and thus personal backlash. I mean in some parts of the world it has become a normality that politicians get death threats and there is shit like stochastic terrorism, in that if you radicalize people more and more you increase the chance that some individuals will snap. So if that poses a significant threat, leads to friends and families turn away to avoid the press and whatnot then this can have major detrimental effects on the judges personally and their mental health. I mean we see daily how celebrities often fail to handle that and being a public figure is by now literally part of their profession. So guess how that works out for people who are not accustomed to that. So that might be an attempt to shoot the messenger rather than the message.
Edit: I mean the thing is, assuming the judge is not actually a communist (not sure that would be illegal in the first place as long as it doesn't interfere with his job, but that's a different question) and hasn't done anything so fundamentally wrong that the politician has a legal handle to impeach them or whatever a removal process would be called and who would be in charge of it, then there isn't going to be anything done. While if you simultaneously plant the narrative that something is wrong and that nobody is doing anything about it (correct no one does... BECAUSE nothing was wrong), then this naturally causes a radicalization process where the reactions might become increasingly more extreme because all the performative slaps apparently don't change the situation (and were never able or supposed to), so more extreme measures are "necessary". So that dynamic can actually lead to real problems, that are based on fake ones.
The other thing is, if you accuse a judge of being biased, you usually also imply that you'd like to "rectify" that. So often enough that is an attempt to gain political approval for a de facto coup d'état where someone wants to replace judges and stuff the highest court with even more biased people (just with a different sort of bias, turning an independent institution into a political one) or by reducing the independence and power of the judicial branch threatening the separation of powers and so on.
The other way around can be seen in the U.S. where the legal way to change the constitution would be by going through congress and/or passing a respective law with high majorities in a majority of states or whatnot (again long and tedious process and likely for a reason), but where instead apparently the supreme court is stuffed with politically biased judges who "make law" by "interpreting" what the existing constitution says, playing the ball back to congress to either accept that or rectify it via the official process.
So it's not too far fetched to see such personal attacks as an attempt to shortcut the official process, which does pose a threat to the legal and judicial process and casts doubts about the stability of the entire system. So ironically it might actually come down to the court of public opinion as to how much of those shenanigans that undermine how the process is supposed to function and where they argue that this is not how it's supposed to be done and that if they actually have a problem they should exhaust their effective options before effectively asking for a coup and the destruction of the system.

Something that doesn't seem to be mentioned but if the people that are responsible for appointing them to the position and possibly appointing them to higher positions openly criticize them it can impact their decisions.
If a judge has the possibility of being appointed to a higher court later in their career and they get criticized by the people who control that appointment they could change how they go about making their deicsions in order to keep a shot at that appiontment.
This can also impact future judges who have yet to be appointed and want to get appointed for a job.

One of the happy little outcomes of the PiS's rule in Poland was sacking judges the government didn't think were pliable enough.
That obviously has to start somewhere, likely as not with extensive criticism about the partiality and unfitness of the judge, in order to soften up public opinion.  I.e. your exact example.
One politician letting off steam is admittedly no big deal, especially if that gets pushed back against.  A recurring, unchallenged, pattern is another thing entirely.
Google Trump criticism judge and see if the news coverage brings you a nice warm happy fuzzy feeling that all is good, nothing to see, move along citizen.

It's not about what the judges think of themselves, it's about what people at large think of the judges, and by proxy the justice system. If your favourite party's face is heavy on "judges are political biased by personal opinion and can't do their job impartially" guess who starts getting more votes? It ain't the party whose face says "judicial independence of popular opinion is necessarily for democracy".
If a judge's decision is X, and that decision is otherwise upheld on whatever grounds it was made on, political figures talking about how that decision is still somehow wrong because [insert favourite excuse here], in this case the historic he's a commie!!1!, you get people very quickly refusing to trust the system or adhere to its decisions. Find her guilty of assault? Nope, you're a misogynist. Skip his prison sentence for theft? It's because you're just too socialist. Community service and detention instead of prison? You're a fascist stealing their labour. Political commentary that controls, especially negatively, trust in the system suborns the authority of the judiciary to the political opinion of the government or specific members of it - the very meaning of "losing independence ".
The complaints can go every direction anybody feels like, but they all interfere with a judicial system based on justice, fairness, consistency, ethics, transparency, and adherence to the rule of law. Not populism, arbitrariness, individualism, and hidden motivators or actors. The system only works to the extent people trust it to work, and these comments erode that trust, thereby eroding the system's effectiveness.

Can you elaborate on how exactly the loss of trust in the system translates to the loss of independence of judges? Why do they become more dependent when less trusted?
